# What pitfalls should I be wary of when memory mapping BIG files?

Tags: performance, memory, operating-system, mapping

I have a bunch of big files, each file can be over 100GB, the total amount of data can be 1TB and they are all read-only files (just have random reads).

My program does small reads in these files on a computer with about 8GB main memory.

In order to increase performance (no seek() and no buffer copying) i thought about using memory mapping, and basically memory-map the whole 1TB of data.

Although it sounds crazy at first, as main memory << disk, with an insight on how virtual memory works you should see that on 64bit machines there should not be problems.

All the pages read from disk to answer to my read()s will be considered "clean" from the OS, as these pages are never overwritten. This means that all these pages can go directly to the list of pages that can be used by the OS without writing back to disk OR swapping (wash them). This means that the operating system could actually store in physical memory just the LRU pages and would operate just reads() when the page is not in main memory.

This would mean no swapping and no increase in i/o because of the huge memory mapping.

This is theory; what I'm looking for is any of you who has every tried or used such an approach for real in production and can share his experience: are there any practical issues with this strategy?

Comment: Just make sure (if the reads really are uniformally random) to disable the OS prefetching mechanisms...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is correct. With a 64-bit OS you can map 1TB of address space to a file and let the OS manage reading and writing to the file.

You didn't mention what CPU architecture you are on but most of them (including amd64) the CPU maintains a bit in each page table entry as to whether data in the page has been written to. The OS can indeed use that flag to avoid writing pages that haven't been modified back to disk.

There would be no increase in IO just because the mapping is large. The amount of data you actually access would determine that. Most OSes, including Linux and Windows, have a unified page cache model in which cached blocks use the same physical pages of memory as memory mapped pages. I wouldn't expect the OS to use more memory with memory mapping than with cached IO. You're just getting direct access to the cached pages.

One concern you may have is with flushing modified data to disk. I'm not sure what the policy is on your OS specifically but the time between modifying a page and when the OS will actually write that data to disk may be a lot longer than your expecting. Use a flush API to force the data to be written to disk if it's important to have it written by a certain time.

I haven't used file mappings quite that large in the past but I would expect it to work well and at the very least be worth trying.